# Android: Sending notification on app closure doesn't work when app is closed using recent apps. How do I fix this?

Tags: android, background, notifications, foreground

I am trying to code an app which sends a notification sometime after the app is closed. For example sake, I have shown here the case where app sends the notification right after closure. I have used onStop() and onPause() of ActivityLifecycleCallbacks. This works well when the app is closed by pressing the back button or by pressing home screen. But when I press recent apps, it doesnt work!

The reason is every time OnPause/OnStop is called I fetch the name of the activity that is currently running and check if it belongs to my App. If it is so, I do not send a notification. If it is some other application, a notification is sent out. This works well when you press home screen/back button. But in case of 'Recent apps' button, the current activity returns my apps' name even though the app is in background. Even if i destroy it there a notification is not triggered. Can someone suggest a fix? Please see the code. I have shown for onActivityPaused. onActivityStopped has same code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
            .getPackageName();

    //Check if current app is my app, else send a notification
    //Name of my app is "menuapp"
    if(packageName.equals("com.example.android.menuapp"))
    {
        Log.d("MyApp", "Another screen of our app");
        //do nothing as this is another activity in my app
    }
    else
    {
        //function to send notification to system
        myDisplay.displayNote("App closed");
    }
}
```

Also, is there a better way to achieve this? Will features like ActivityLifecycleCallbacks slow down or harm app performance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, you can't do it like that. When user closes your app with recents, android stops all threads. I think, you can achieve the desired behavior with IntentService. Just call startService method before activity stops and show your notification from the Service.